# How to prevent radio button change status

Tags: c#, xaml, radio-button

I am trying to prevent the change status of textbox and radio button when the button (btactive) is clicked. I can use property `IsReadOnly` for textbox but I can not find this property in radio button, Is there anyway to prevent the change status of radiobutton ?
Here is my code :

```
 private void btActive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (check != 0)
        {
            udhour.IsReadOnly = true;
            udmin.IsReadOnly = true;
            testvalue.IsReadOnly = true;
            //How can I set Isreadonly for radio button
        }
    }
```

Comment: u can disable radio button..

Comment: instead use IsEnabled=false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable radio button. use `IsEnabled=false`

Comment: Thank you. this is a solution for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `AutoCheck` property of the RadioButton to `False`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am using XAML not FORM and I can not find this property  "Autocheck"

Answer (score 0):

Add radiobutton.IsEnabled = false in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Write and Checked changed event for the readonly effect.

```
void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radioButton1.Checked = !radioButton1.Checked;
}
```